# Problems with WiredTiger in order to deploy a config server in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to deploy a shared and replicated cluster of MongoDB.
I did the installation like it is indicated in the official page for Ubuntu 20.04: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/.
But, when I executed:

```
mongod --configsvr --port 27001 --replSet config_server --dbpath mongo/data_patients/config/ --bind_ip localhost
```

I have the following trouble:
[image]
and I can't access to the configuration server.

Comment: Is there anything in your specified `--dbpath`, `mongo/data_patients/config/`?

Comment: No, there's nothing there.

Comment: I only created that directory.

Comment: Are there any replica sets and/or other `mongod` instances running?

Comment: No, only it is executed with systemctl start mongod.

Comment: I'm following this: https://geekflare.com/es/mongodb-sharding/ and I'm in Paso 1 on the first command.

Comment: That log indicates it is using the dbpath `data_patients/config/` and logged `Storage engine to use detected by data files`, so there are some sort of files already in the dbpath, and the version of mongodb you are running doesn't know how to open them.  For testing, try creating a new, empty dbpath.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Looks like you use different versions of MongoDB or you mix the dbPath. Note, every mongod instance (in the linked tutorial you start 6 different mongod instances) needs its own dbpath! Also the logPath should be different for each instance. Another note, you should not mix IP-Address and hostnames. Use `localhost` everywhere in your case.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) And you should not start with the most challenging setup. Start with a stand-alone MongoDB, then a [Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) and finally a Sharded Cluster. [This one](https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick) may also help. It is for Windows, but the config files are very similar and the JS-Scripts are the same.

Comment: That's solved. Thank's Wernfried and Joe. The problem was that in an error in the dbpath there was some trash from a previous error. I change the version to 5.0.14 and clean the dbpath and all works.